# qrying DB where two customers in one order

Tags: sql

lets say I have two tables, 
**Order**
order_id (PK)
ordered_date

**CustomerOrders**
Customer_order_id (PK)
order_id (FK)
customer_type(char1) ( can be S, T and M)

If one or more different types of customers involved in an order, the table will look like
**Order**
order_id  5
order_date '05-06-2020'

**CusotmerOrder**
customer_order_id 1
order_id 5
type 'M'

customer_order_id 2
order_id 5
type 'S'

and so on

How can I write a qry that will return all unique order_ids that have combination of S and M type customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy self join query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.order_id
FROM CustomerOrders AS M
INNER JOIN CustomerOrders AS S
  ON M.order_id = S.order_id
WHERE M.customer_type = 'M'
  AND S.customer_type = 'S'
```

Comment: @lollahmullah, both answers do work. You need to use correct field names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists:

```
Select distinct order_id 
from CustomerOrder co
where exists (select * from CustomerOrder co1 
   where co.order_id = co1.order_id and co1.Type = 'M') and
exists (select * from CustomerOrder co1 
   where co.order_id = co1.order_id and co1.Type = 'S');
```

Comment: @lollahmullah, it does work. Probably you tried to write it as is without renaming to match your field names.

Comment: of course I did. my 'self inner join' works but 'where exists' does not.. we can find on closer inspection why that is which I will do tmorow...thanks again, I might also need to find out performance wise which is better as well

Comment: @lollahmullah, here is dbfiddle link that shows both inner join and exists DO WORK:
  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fdbcc78bd5bc0fd10af087e47ebb2d84